# Why is my late 2013 iMac so slow?

Tags: imac, ssd, memory, performance

For the last three months I have been more or less enjoying my new late 2013 21" iMac. I already have an early 2011 MBP, which is pretty maxed out with a 512GB SSD and 8 GB of RAM, and still feels very, very fast.

The iMac has 8 GB RAM as well, but "only" the Intel Iris GPU and a 1TB SATA HDD. Both machines are running OS X 10.9.4.

Starting up a few apps, like Mail, Safari and maybe iPhoto, takes ages. Sometimes up to 20 or 30 seconds. Whereas the MBP takes only a handful seconds. It's clear to me that the SSD gives a great performance advantage. But is it really that much...?

I also noticed in the systems report that the Iris uses sometimes up to 1.5 GB of RAM. This seems like a lot. I imagine that this could also hurt performance.

I also get a lot messages like these in the system log:

```
24.08.14 19:57:32,827 WindowServer[539]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "iPhoto" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
```

These happen if I switch from one iPhoto event to another, or switch to my iCloud albums. On the MBP this happens instantly, without delay.

Update: Here are some screenshots of the activity monitor and Console logging:

[image: CPU load]
[image: HDD load]
[image: RAM usage]
[image: Console logging]

Comment: can you provide us with a screen shot of your activity monitor!

Comment: Can do that later

Comment: Added some screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Yosemite did make things quite a bit better. It's still a bit sluggish sometimes, but overall response times are much better.

Also, the spotlight indexing took quite a hit.

Comment: One more thing: I opened a bug ticket with Apple and they said it was a botched Aperture library migration. However, I fixed it myself by re-installing the whole Mac. While at it, I added an external Thunderbolt-SSD to build a fusion drive. This was REALLY a good idea making the machine so much faster.

Answer (score 1):

i've seen this on some of my machines... it is fixable (though ican't remember the details for my situation). but it will stay very slow until you clean out those ui/windowserver errors.

firstly:
have you added any screensavers?
have you safe booted to clean out caches and check HD?

http://www.macworld.com/article/1163410/bugs_and_fixes_when_os_x_lion_slows_to_a_crawl.html

Comment: No, but I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

That console message means iPhoto was doing so much processing on the main UI thread that it couldn't even supply updated UI to the windowserver for a few seconds.

It could be your iCloud Photostream acting up in iPhoto. I had this issue and had to disable photostream.